Multi Module Angular Project After add New Sub Module Not Naviagating.No Errors Display
I have a Multi Module angular project that i have been working and today i had to add new sub module (AdvertisingModule).I have configured all routing and code without any error.but when i click button inside the new module it has to navigate to it's child page.No errors in console URL also changing but UI does not change.Here i have listed my App module and new module.how can i find the error ..?
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules  } from '@angular/router'; 

import { PagesComponent } from './pages/pages.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './pages/not-found/not-found.component';
import { AdminGuardService } from './Auth/admin-guard.service';


export const routes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '', 
        component: PagesComponent, children: [
            { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
            { path: 'account', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/account/account.module').then(m => m.AccountModule), data: { breadcrumb: 'Account Settings' } },
            { path: 'compare', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/compare/compare.module').then(m => m.CompareModule), data: { breadcrumb: 'Compare' } },
            { path: 'wishlist', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/wishlist/wishlist.module').then(m => m.WishlistModule), data: { breadcrumb: 'Wishlist' } },
            { path: 'cart', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/cart/cart.module').then(m => m.CartModule), data: { breadcrumb: 'Shopping Cart' } },
            { path: 'checkout', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/checkout/checkout.module').then(m => m.CheckoutModule), data: { breadcrumb: 'Checkout' }},
            { path: 'contact', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/contact/contact.module').then(m => m.ContactModule), data: { breadcrumb: 'Contact' }},
            { path: 'brands', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/brands/brands.module').then(m => m.BrandsModule), data: { breadcrumb: 'Brands' } },
            { path: 'products', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/products/products.module').then(m => m.ProductsModule), data: { breadcrumb: 'All Products' }}
            
        ]
    },
    { path: 'retail', loadChildren: () => import('./retail/retail.module').then(m => m.RetailModule), data: { breadcrumb: 'Foggy Frog Retail' }},
    { path: 'landing', loadChildren: () => import('./landing/landing.module').then(m => m.LandingModule),canActivate : [AdminGuardService] },
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule) , canActivate : [AdminGuardService]},
    { path: 'sign-in', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/sign-in/sign-in.module').then(m => m.SignInModule), data: { breadcrumb: 'Sign In ' }},
    { path: 'advertiesments', loadChildren: () => import('./advertising/advertising.module').then(m => m.AdvertisingModule), data: { breadcrumb: 'Foggy Frog Advertising' }},
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];



@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, // <- comment this line for activate lazy load
            relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy',
            initialNavigation: 'enabled'  // for one load page, without reload
            // useHash: true
        })
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

This is my newly added module
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SelectListComponent } from './select-list/select-list.component';
import { PictureViewerComponent } from './picture-viewer/picture-viewer.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { InputFileConfig, InputFileModule } from 'ngx-input-file';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { selectlistResolver } from './select-list/selectlistResolver';
import { pictureViewerResolver } from './picture-viewer/pictureViewerResolver';
import { advertisingComponent } from './advertising.component';
const config: InputFileConfig = {
  fileAccept: '*'
};

export const routes = [
  {
    path : 'internal',
    component : advertisingComponent,
    children : [
      { path : 'list' , component : SelectListComponent , resolve : { cres : selectlistResolver }},
      { path : 'preview/:listID' , component : PictureViewerComponent ,data: { breadcrumb: 'Manage User Account' },resolve : {cres : pictureViewerResolver}} 
    ]
  }
 
]


@NgModule({
  declarations: [PictureViewerComponent,SelectListComponent,advertisingComponent],
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SharedModule,
    InfiniteScrollModule,
    CommonModule
  ]
  ,
  providers : [selectlistResolver,pictureViewerResolver]
})
export class AdvertisingModule { }

See below picture it's loading without any issue for internal URL also

but when i press action button it change the URL as below picture and stay in same screen

this is the code for action button
async OpenList() {
    this.router.navigate(['/advertiesments/internal/preview/38c7f9ec-fd0b-4338-9959-e254c32678b9']);

   
  }

how can i find the error since this not display any error.
Update advertising Component Code
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { map } from 'rxjs';
import { TokenWithEmail } from 'src/app/Global/Models';
import { ApiserviceService } from 'src/app/Global/apiservice.service';
import { advertisingInfo } from 'src/app/app.models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-list',
  templateUrl: './advertising.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./advertising.component.scss']
})
export class advertisingComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private apiservice : ApiserviceService, private router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log("Image list Open");
     // this.router.navigate(['/advertiesments/internal/list']);
   
  }



  async OpenList() {

   
    this.router.navigate(['/preview/38c7f9ec-fd0b-4338-9959-e254c32678b9']);

   
  }




}

HTML Code
<h4 class="py-2"> Available Advertisement Lists </h4>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="OpenList()">Action</button>

scss
.body{
    background-color: black;
}

Picture Viewer Component Code
<div class="picture-viewer" >
    <img [src]="pictures[currentIndex]?.imagepath" alt="Picture" class="picture" />
    <div class="controls">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggleFullScreen()">
        <!-- <mat-icon>{{ isFullScreen ? 'fullscreen_exit' : 'fullscreen' }}</mat-icon> -->
      </button>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="refreshPictures()">
        <!-- <mat-icon>refresh</mat-icon> -->
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  

TS File Code
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { IImage } from 'src/app/app.models';
import { ApiserviceService } from 'src/app/Global/apiservice.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-picture-viewer',
  templateUrl: './picture-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./picture-viewer.component.scss']
})
export class PictureViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  pictures: IImage[] = [];
  currentIndex = 0;
  intervalId: any;
  isFullScreen = false;

  constructor(private apiservice : ApiserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log("CCCCCCCCCC *** I came Here");
    
    this.loadPictures();
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'Escape' && this.isFullScreen) {
        this.exitFullScreen();
      }
    });
  }

  loadPictures(): void {

    this.apiservice.GetAdvertisingSingleList('38c7f9ec-fd0b-4338-9959-e254c32678b9').subscribe(x=>{
      this.pictures = x.imagelist;
      console.log(this.pictures);
      this.startSlideshow();
    });

    // this.pictureService.fetchPictures().subscribe(pictures => {
    //   this.pictures = pictures;
    //   this.startSlideshow();
    // }, error => {
    //   this.pictures = this.pictureService.getCachedPictures();
    //   this.startSlideshow();
    // });
  }

  startSlideshow(): void {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.currentIndex = (this.currentIndex + 1) % this.pictures.length;
    }, 3000); // Change picture every 3 seconds
  }

  stopSlideshow(): void {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }

  refreshPictures(): void {
    this.stopSlideshow();
    this.loadPictures();
  }

  toggleFullScreen(): void {
    this.isFullScreen = !this.isFullScreen;
    if (this.isFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    }
  }

  exitFullScreen(): void {
    if (this.isFullScreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
      this.isFullScreen = false;
    }
  }
}


please share the contents of advertisingComponent HTML and TS also try removing the resolver and checking

Updated the code.I tried removing the resolver and still the same issue

Router outlet is missing, without this, angular will not render the child routes, that is the problem!
<h4 class="py-2"> Available Advertisement Lists </h4>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="OpenList()">Action</button>
<router-outlet/> <!-- changed here! -->


It worked.simple impossible to find mistake.Thanks
